# Request parameter filtering on update action of HABTM model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, entity-relationship

A Doctor can perform surgeries at many Hospitals.

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :hospitals
end
```

A Hospital can have many Doctors performing surgeries in it.

```
class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors
end
```

The new join table migration looks like this.

```
class CreateDoctorsHospitals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :doctors_hospitals, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :doctor
      t.belongs_to :hospital

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

We would like to update the `@doctor` object, and give it some Hospitals.

```
<%= form_for(@doctor) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :notes %><br>
<%= f.text_area :notes %><br>
<%= f.label :hospitals %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :hospital_ids, Hospital.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %><br>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The generated HTML looks like this.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/doctors/1" class="edit_doctor" id="edit_doctor_1" method="post">
  <div>
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="xxx">
  </div>
  <label for="doctor_notes">Notes</label><br>
  <textarea id="doctor_notes" name="doctor[notes]"></textarea><br>
  <label class="control-label" for="doctor_hospitals">Hospitals</label><br>
  <input name="doctor[hospital_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">
    <select class="form-control" id="doctor_hospital_ids" multiple="multiple" name="doctor[hospital_ids][]">
      <option value="1">First Hospital</option>
      <option value="2">Second Hospital</option>
      ...
      <option value="n">Nth Hospital</option
    </select>
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Doctor">
</form>
```

The DoctorsController's relevant snippets are here.

```
class DoctorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_doctor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @doctor.update(doctor_params)
        format.html { redirect_to edit_doctor_hospitals_path, notice: 'Doctor was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @doctor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def set_doctor
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def doctor_params
    params.require(:doctor).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :status, :notes, :hospital_ids)
  end
end
```

While in the Update method, `@doctor` has been set: `set_doctor` has grabbed the doctor's id from the elusive '`params`' and found the record and it's all good.

But look at the doctor param!! -> `params[:doctor]=>{"notes"=>"Here be notes"}`. Where are the `hospital_ids`? Here's what `params` looks like:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "_method"=>"patch", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", 
  "doctor"=>{
    "notes"=>"Here be notes"
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Update Doctor", 
  "action"=>"update", 
  "controller"=>"doctors", 
  "id"=>"1"
}
```

If we look into `request.params` at this very same moment, we'll see that it includes the `hospital_ids`! Wonderful!

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "_method"=>"patch", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", 
  "doctor"=>{
    "notes"=>"Here be notes", 
    "hospital_ids"=>["", "1", "4", "10"] # I don't know what that blank one is for, but whatever.
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Update Doctor", 
  "action"=>"update", 
  "controller"=>"doctors", 
  "id"=>"1"
}
```

So what is going on? I assume that `params` gets its data from `request.params`, so why does it lose `hospital_ids`?

`@doctor.update(doctor_params)` is obviously not updating the model with any hospitals.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HABTM, use require params like this:

```
  def doctor_params
    params.require(:doctor).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :status, :notes, {:hospital_ids => []})
  end
```

Reference - https://coderwall.com/p/_1oejq

Comment: Woah! This is totally it. I've been pulling my hair out for hours over this, thank you kindly.